# Does the E90 320i 2006 use the same Coils and O2 sensors as the E90 328i?

Tags: bmw, ignition-coil, e90, 320i

I'm looking on eBay for replacement parts for my E90 320i 2006, but I can't find anything for it. In the results I always find replacement parts for the 325i, 328i, etc., but not for my 320i 2006. I would like to know if someone could guide me and tell me which other model I can buy parts for my vehicle.

Thanks

Comment: Check out different suppliers : ebay is not the only purveyor of motor spares. Do note your question will be closed as it is essentially a shopping question.

Comment: Ahhh i just want to know, if the 320i use the same parts as the 328i. Coils, o2 sensor, etc

Comment: Don't trust only ebay... try other sources... and they may have the info...

Comment: It would help if you would be more specific about the part that you are looking for. Without that knowledge, we're trying to guess what you're planning.

Answer (score 1):

Your 320i is a European model. If you're looking for parts from the States, you won't find them there. Looking on [this website](https://www.onlinecarparts.co.uk/bosch-667407.html), I found a Bosch part number for your ignition coil which is PN: 0221504471 ... here in the States, the coil for a 325i is shown as [Bosch PN: 0221504470](http://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/bmw,2006,325i,3.0l+l6,1431851,ignition,ignition+coil,7060). The two parts certainly look the same and are probably interchangeable, but there is no guarantee. From the looks of it, the 4470 is used for all of these models available in the US:

```
BMW 1 SERIES M  2011
BMW 128I    2008-2013
BMW 135I    2008-2010
BMW 323I    2006-2011
BMW 325CI   2003-2006
BMW 325I    2003-2006
BMW 325XI   2003-2006
BMW 328I    2007-2013
BMW 328XI   2007-2008
BMW 330CI   2003-2006
BMW 330I    2003-2006
BMW 330XI   2003-2006
BMW 335I    2007-2010
BMW 335IS   2011-2013
BMW 335XI   2007-2008
BMW 525I    2003-2007
BMW 525XI   2006-2007
BMW 528I    2008-2011
BMW 528XI   2008
BMW 530I    2003-2007
BMW 530XI   2006-2007
BMW 535I    2008-2010
BMW 535XI   2008
BMW 545I    2004-2005
BMW 550I    2006-2016
BMW 550I GT 2010-2017
BMW 645CI   2004-2005
BMW 650I    2006-2016
BMW 740I    2011-2012
BMW 740LI   2011-2012
BMW 745I    2002-2005
BMW 745LI   2002-2005
BMW 750I    2006-2017
BMW 750LI   2009-2015
BMW 760I    2004-2006
BMW 760LI   2003-2015
BMW ALPINA B6   2015-2017
BMW ALPINA B6 GRAN COUPE    2016
BMW ALPINA B7   2007-2015
BMW ALPINA B7L  2011-2013
BMW M5  2013-2016
BMW M6  2012-2016
BMW X3  2004-2012
BMW X5  2003-2016
BMW X6  2008-2016
BMW Z4  2003-2016
```

It is very possible this coil will work in your vehicle. At the price point, it may be worth your time to try (unless you can actually get the 4471 version).

Answer (score 1):

Paulster2 has the right idea but the best answer for BMWs is to look at [realoem.com](http://realoem.com) this provides a view into the actual BMW parts database.  It also covers all markets, so you can easily figure out what parts are on your car and then by clicking on the part number it will show you all the cars where that part was used.

In the case of your ignition coil you will get something like this:

```
12137559842
Ignition coil
DELPHI
From:12/01/2012To:-Weight:0.250 kgPrice:
Supersedes:
12137638477 (04/01/2012 — 09/30/2013), Exchangeable    retrospectively
12137594935 (01/01/2009 — 06/19/2017), Exchangeable retrospectively
12137582627 (07/18/2007 — 01/30/2009), Exchangeable retrospectively
12137571644 (12/01/2006 — 10/12/2007)

Part 12137559842 was found on the following E90 vehicles:
3' E90, 316i, Sedan, N43, EUR, (VF31) : Ignition coil/spark plug
3' E90, 316i, Sedan, N43, EUR, (VF32) : Ignition coil/spark plug
3' E90, 318i, Sedan, N43, EUR, (VF51) : Ignition coil/spark plug
3' E90, 318i, Sedan, N43, EUR, (VF52) : Ignition coil/spark plug
3' E90, 320i, Sedan, N43, EUR, (VF91) : Ignition coil/spark plug
3' E90, 320i, Sedan, N43, EUR, (VF92) : Ignition coil/spark plug
3' E90, 325i, Sedan, N53, EUR, (VE31) : Ignition coil/spark plug
3' E90, 325i, Sedan, N53, EUR, (VE32) : Ignition coil/spark plug
3' E90, 325xi, Sedan, N53, EUR, (VE51) : Ignition coil/spark plug
3' E90, 330i, Sedan, N53, EUR, (VE71) : Ignition coil/spark plug
3' E90, 330i, Sedan, N53, EUR, (VE72) : Ignition coil/spark plug
3' E90, 330xi, Sedan, N53, EUR, (VE91) : Ignition coil/spark plug
```

So, it looks like the coil is the same between both engines in Europe, but it also looks to be market specific.  Don't take that a definitive, I had to make some guesses about your car to get there, and I might be starting from a wrong part.

BMW is all about reusing parts across their various product lines.  I use this all the time when working on my older BMW to track down parts.